# How to highlight QToolButton

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget

I'm trying to programmatically make a QToolButton highlighted when it gains focus. I would like it to be highlighted exactly like when it is selected by mouse hover. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how familiar you are with stylesheets but this one ought to get you started:

```
QPushButton:hover { background-color: rgb(224, 255, 0); }
QPushButton:focus { background-color: green; }
```